# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration or timeout:

Tags: java, testing, selenium, automated-tests, bamboo

My problem is that selenium give the exception so visible elements. I don't understand this because when I put  to build in my machine works! ( The tests build at bamboo).

This is a  exception:

```html
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration or timeout: 30.06 seconds Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', time: '2014-10-23 13:11:40' System info: host: 'N/A', ip: 'N/A', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-52-virtual', java.version: '1.7.0_72' Session ID: 1757208d-d49e-4792-b053-e55e7300c233 Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=34.0}]
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 30.06 seconds
```

Code:

```
String name;
String key;

@Before
public void setUp() throws InterruptedException {

    driver.findElement(By.id("menu_topMenu.maintenance")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("menu_topMenu.route")).click();
}

@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {

    AddRoute addRoute = new AddRoute(driver);
    addRoute.add();
    name = addRoute.getName();
    key = addRoute.getKey();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#Route_btn_novo")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#Route_key > input[type=\"text\"]")).sendKeys(key);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#Route_description > input[type=\"text\"]")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#Route_description > input[type=\"text\"]")).sendKeys(name);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#Route_organization > div.lookUpHitArea")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#MonetUIFieldsLookupGridContainer_organization > div.slick-pane.slick-pane-top.slick-pane-left > div.slick-viewport.slick-viewport-top.slick-viewport-left > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.slick-cell.l0.r0.cell-row")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#Route_plannedCost > input")).sendKeys("10000");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#Route_origin > div.lookUpHitArea")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#MonetUIFieldsLookupGridContainer_location > div.slick-pane.slick-pane-top.slick-pane-left > div.slick-viewport.slick-viewport-top.slick-viewport-left > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.slick-cell.l1.r1.cell-row.selected")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#Route_lastStopIsDestination > input")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#Route_btn_save_and_close")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    assertTrue("Rota existente nao validada corretamente",
            isDisplayedByCssSelector(driver, "#form_and_grid > div > div.monetInlineAlerContainer > div"));
}
```

}

I don't know more what to do!

Comment: I wonder how are you executing the tests?

Comment: This exception are happening when I executing at bamboo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how your entire set up looks like. But, a common practice is to use [Selenium Grid](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) in such case. The idea is to have a selenium hub and multiple slaves(as many as you need and may be virtual machines) and have the CI server controlling the slaves to execute the tests. The issue you are having is because of CI server is not acting like your local machine is doing. The element is not visible means selenium is not able to interact with the browser which it should not on CI. See [this](http://grid.selenium.googlecode.com/git-history/22ed3ff910401af083bf06a4d13514f4c6a623ca/src/main/webapp/how_it_works.html) to explore more about the grid. [This](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) should help you to get started.

*Note: This is one of many ways to execute selenium tests from CI*