# Bamboo with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, bamboo

**Tools**: Java, Selenium WebDriver, Maven, Git, Bamboo

I'm not sure how I can run my test-cases under Bamboo which are written by java and build by maven and stored into Git repository. Bamboo can't open a real browser (IE, Firefox, chrome..)
It's worked when I tried to use HTMLUnitdriver (headless browser) instead of a real browser, BUT the problem with HTMLUnitdriver it is not functioning well (actually, it can't run most of the test scenarios even the other browsers do flawlessly).

I've Google it but could not found any good information on how to do it.

I'll really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not run any test on `Bamboo` server. CI server is not meant to run any tests on. It should only controls how the tests will be executed instead. There are multiple ways to handle this. `Selenium Grid` is highly recommended. See another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800002/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotvisibleexception-element-is-not-currently-visible/27804334#27804334) on same topic

Comment: I didn't get your point regrading "should not run any test on Bamboo server".

Comment: @SarahQA **Bamboo can't open a real browser (IE, Firefox, chrome..) It's worked when I tried to use HTMLUnitdriver (headless browser) instead of a real browser** You should not run any test on Bamboo server. Bamboo should only trigger the UI tests machine to run them. Have you gone through the link I provide?

Comment: Thank you. I managed to setup the grid (Hub & nodes).. but now I want to start the Hub & the Node automatically not manually. as you know... any help

Comment: Yes, you can keep the configuration in a `json` file and create a batch file to execute the commands to start the hub and node. From Bamboo it's pretty simple to execute the batch commands See my thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842774/error-forwarding-the-new-session-selenium-grid-2)

Answer (score 0):

Use BrowserStack to execute test scripts and download reports/results as part of build as an artefact.

Or specify an agent that has the browser you need to test on.

https://www.browserstack.com/automate

Comment: Thank you, I tried it .. it very easy to use BUT I can't use it because BrowserStack can't access the testing environment in my company

Comment: Using the BrowserStack Local Testing capabilities you will be able to access locally hosted apps, its fairly easy to set up

http://www.browserstack.com/local-testing