# Selenium Tests hang when attempting to be run with Bamboo

Tags: java, maven, selenium, bamboo

I'm attempting to use Bamboo's build and deployment capabilities to run Selenium Automated tests with my project.

We're currently using a Maven task to build and run regular JUNIT tests, and the plan is to use another Maven task to run the Selenium tests after the code has been successfully deployed to the server.  At the moment, everything seems to run just fine locally, but when bamboo attempts to run the Selenium tests it seems to hang indefinitely.  Unfortunately I don't have remote access to the server to watch it first hand, but I do know that it's a Microsoft server running with OS version: Windows 2012 R2 64-bit.  I also know that the server is using java version "1.8.0_101", which is the same as my local setup.  I've included a sample of the code I'm running below.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class SeleniumTestExample {
WebDriver driver;
@Before
public void setup(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "src/test/resources/IEDriverServer32bit.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(null, ieCapabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://google.com");
}

@Test
public void printPageTitle(){
    System.out.println("Title of Page is: " + driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

When run through Bamboo, the only output in the logs are the lines...

> Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
>
> 2.53.1.0
>
> Listening on port 8080
>
> Only local connections are allowed

Comment: where are you trying to run your tests , on CI (bamboo) server?

Comment: Yes I'm attempting to run these tests on a bamboo server, but could you elaborate a little more on your question?

Answer (score 0):

CI or Bamboo server should be used for controlling your tests. You should not try to run your tests on a CI server. The issue you are having is probably because of that. Your are trying to use CI server as you local machine, which it will not respond the same way as your local. Instead you should use [selenium grid](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) in your setup to remotely connect to a machine by making use of hub and node. You may also have to use [remote webdriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/remote.html). Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588411/bamboo-with-selenium-webdriver) post

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this using TeamCity, in this case the IE tells you that its executable will only accept connections from the local machine. According to [Selenium org](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#running-iedriverserverexe-remotely)

> The HTTP server started by the IEDriverServer.exe sets an access control list to only accept connections from the local machine, and disallows incoming connections from remote machines. At present, this cannot be changed without modifying the source code to the IEDriverServer.exe. To run the Internet Explorer driver on a remote machine, use the Java standalone remote server in connection with your language binding's equivalent of RemoteWebDriver.

So first run a chromedriver via passing through a param like so :

```
chromedriver --whitelisted-ips=""
```

This will basically whitelist all IP's, not always an ideal solution of course. But will show you that your tests can run on this CI configuration. Next thing to look for is your users privileges. Ask your admin to grant you more permissions in order to do your job. Keep in mind that IE's Protected mode may require some additional changes from your user. If none of this helps, consider [Selenium grid](http://mrbluecoat.blogspot.bg/2014/05/set-up-selenium-on-windows-including-ie.html?m=1) with IE nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get rid of the line in the code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "src/test/resources/IEDriverServer32bit.exe");
```

First of all, it tells where selenium should look for the webdriver for IE. Since the Bamboo server is a windows machine, you have to set it up with the absolute path of the file, like "C:\test\webdriver\IEDriverServer32bit.exe".

Secondly, the property could be set using environment variables of the Bamboo task.

Thirdly, if you want to define it on the fly, you can define the property in pom.xml as:

`<webdriver.ie.driver.path>
    C:\test\webdriver\IEDriverServer32bit.exe
</webdriver.ie.driver.path>`

and use it in a system property with help of maven-surefire-plugin.

then you can run test with the command

`mvn test -Dwebdriver.ie.driver.path=C:\test\webdriver\IEDriverServer32bit.exe`

with whatever path you want.