# Run Selenium Grid on Bamboo using Docker

Tags: docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, bamboo

I'm trying to run my tests on Atlassian Bamboo Server(version 7.2.2), but it impossible to do because they contain Selenium - "Bamboo can't open a real browser (IE, Firefox, chrome..)"[[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588411/bamboo-with-selenium-webdriver)].

So, I started Selenium Grid on my localhost using dockers selenium/hub and selenium/node-chrome-browser as it describes in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lBaedX4UAE).

Main commands to run Selenium Grid with chrome webdriver:

1. `docker run -d -p 4545:4444 --name selenium-hub selenium/hub`
2. `docker run -d -P --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome-debug`

It works very well, but only on my localhost, on remote Bamboo Server I can't configure this - selenium-hub works, but my selenium/node-chrome-debug can't link to the localhost:4545, where my selenium hub
located

I got exception `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities {browserName: chrome, version: }`

This is exactly the same exception on my localhost if I run only the first docker so I figured out that my second docker doesn't work as it should be.

There is a configuration of my dockers:

[first docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuJYa.png) => run selenium/hub on port 4545

[the second docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raYK7.png) => run selenium/node-chrome-debug on port 5900, also active "Link to detached containers" and '-P' in "Additional arguments"